# How set up decorative EB Garamond initials within ConTeXt?

Tags: context

You can get this [page](http://tex-talk.net/2011/08/putting-colors-in-initials/) to print nice two-color drop caps with LaTeX, but what about ConTeXt?
I can not figure out how to implement both letters. Is it due to an issue either with ConTeXt or a problem with LuaTeX?
Why there is nothing about it through all the pages I have browsed the last days?

Comment: »Why there is nothing about it through all the pages I have browsed the last days?«  Because not all problems in the world have already been solved by someone else.  Also, probably because drop caps and especially coloured drop caps are pretty useless.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I was very surprised that nobody had suffered this problem before with ConTeXt. Most likely, I am not the first, of course, but almost certainly the matter has not been debated, I suppose. I wonder if there is any more elegant way of solving it, if at all. But the current solution is enough for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a `lettrine` module for ConTeXt but it is, at least in my opinion, totally over-engineered and not even generic.  That is why I simply use regular Plain TeX machinery.  You need to download EBGaramond from [its homepage](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/), exactly [here](http://georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/fonts/), to get the two files `EBGaramond-InitialsF1.otf` and `EBGaramond-InitialsF2.otf`.  Simply place them somewhere where ConTeXt can find them.  Then use the following code.

```
\definefontsynonym [LettrineBack] [file:EBGaramond-InitialsF1.otf]
\definefontsynonym [LettrineFont] [file:EBGaramond-InitialsF2.otf]

\define\coloredlettrine{\dodoubleempty\docoloredlettrine}

\starttexdefinition docoloredlettrine [#1][#2]#3
  \noindent
  \hangindent=2\lineheight
  \hangafter=-2
  \hbox to 0pt{
    \hskip-\hangindent
    \smash{
      \lower .8\lineheight \hbox{
        \rlap{\color[#1]{\definedfont[LettrineBack at 1.8\lineheight]#3}}
        \color[#2]{\definedfont[LettrineFont at 1.8\lineheight]#3}
      }
    }
    \hfill
  }
\stoptexdefinition

\setupbodyfont[ebgaramond]

\starttext

\coloredlettrine[darkblue][darkred]{A}{\sc fter the three} \input ward

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful, but it might be worth noting that the EB Garamond initials fonts are setup for the letters A, F, G, L, N, O, Q and T, only.

Comment: Thanks, Ross. I knew it. It's just that I have a page in which the protagonist is an epigraph that will be printed in old style. I have not yet chosen this citation. But if, by chance, the text of the quotation begins with any of the initials, I would like to take advantage of those that EB Garamond does have complete. My novel will be totally printed in black and white. So the background of the initial would be gray, and the capital letter itself would be black.

Comment: @ebohoyod 'the protagonist is an epigraph': are you sure? Wouldn't that make for a rather short novel?

Comment: I had written: "I have a page in which..." (a page is only that: "a page"). And, moreover, since there is no more than one epigraph in this page, it is the absolute protagonist within the page, figuratively speaking, of course.

Comment: @HenriMenke I have been playing a bit with the lettrine module and with your code, and after a while exploring the possibilities, I must admit that not only I can not figure out  anything better than your solution, but also I think it is very powerful and could not be simpler than it already is.
I'm not a developer and the most I consider myself only as a rookie user of ConTeXt, but I sense that your procedure is excellent.